# Radio buttons not working to select something

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a dialogue box that contains 3 radio buttons and a "Present" button to be used with some projector software we have. What I want to do is, after clicking "Present", open a file specific to which room was chosen with the radio buttons.

The issue is, after clicking "Present" nothing happens.

I know `Process.Start` and `present_Click` are correct; in a test project I did the "Present" button successfully opens a file. I am sure the `CheckedChanged` parts are probably incorrect, but I am confused as to what to do with them.

Here's my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           public void present_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               if (room1.Checked)
               {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room1.txt");
               }
               else if (room2.Checked)
               {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room2.txt");
               }
               else if (room3.Checked)
               {
                   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room3.txt");
               }
           }

           private void room1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               room1.Checked = true;
           }

           private void room2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               room2.Checked = true;
           }

           private void room3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               room3.Checked = true;
           }
       }
```

Can someone please help me with these radio buttons?

Comment: why not put some try{}catch{} blocks in your code.. also what happens when you try to debug the small code

Answer (score 3):

Your CheckedChanged event handlers are definitely messed up.

In english, your logic says

> Anytime a radio button's checked status is changed, set its checked property to true

Honestly I'm surprised you don't get into some infinite loop where every control is fighting to be the "selected one". Removing that logic altogether may well fix your problem. It also seems odd that you are "starting" a text file, but I assume that is intentional.

The important knowledge here is that a user clicking the radio button automatically sets the `Checked` property. There is no need to do it yourself in code-behind.

Comment: Thought my logic seemed off... Yeah, the text files "starting" was just for testing purposes. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the events which trigger upon checking or unchecking. If I understand properly, you only want 'something' to happen when you click `Present`. So once someone clicks `Present`, then verify which checkboxes are on/off and do the appropriate thing:

Sorry if I'm making the wrong assumptions, feel free to correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void present_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (room1.Checked)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room1.txt");
            }
            else if (room2.Checked)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room2.txt");
            }
            else (room3.Checked)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"room3.txt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The else is actually better (though not technically needed) as it allows the evaluation to "short-circuit" as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That's assuming that you only want 1 and only 1 room process to happen once you click present, in which case just use 3 buttons: `Present1`, `Present2`, `Present3`. This is unusual since the OP is using 3 checkboxes, which maybe implies that multiple things should happen at once.

Comment: He said "Radio buttons" (not check boxes) implying that he only wants one. Perhaps he doesn't want 3 buttons for UX reasons. You are correct in stating that else would break the functionality if it were check boxes though.

Comment: @Vlad Thank you for your answer, I ended up using 3 buttons like you suggested. The code you answered with is what I originally had, which did not work either. However the three buttons works very well, I had only wanted radio buttons in case a user selected the wrong room. Thanks for your help!